# Azure not finding custom deploy.cmd

Tags: django, azure, deployment, kudu

I have a Django project that I have hosted on Azure.  I'm need to add deployment which execute upon each deployment.  I've used kuduscript to generate custom deployment scripts, and my file structure now looks like such:

```
- site/
- app/
- manage.py
- requirements.txt
- .deployment
- deploy.cmd
```

I haven't made any changes to either the .deployment or deploy.cmd file.  Yet when I run

```
git push azure master
```

I get the following error messages:

```
Running custom deployment command...
Not setting execute permissions for deploy.cmd
Running deployment command...
/opt/Kudu/bin/Scripts/starter.sh: line2: exec: deploy.cmd: not found
App container will begin restart within 10 seconds
Error - Changes committed to remote repository but deployment to website failed
```

Any idea on why the deploy.cmd can't be found?